# Ubuntu booting stuck at checking battery status after upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My ubuntu version was 10.04 and it was continuously giving me the prompt

> please upgrade your version

Then finally I did that. Upgraded it from "Update Manager". It downloaded all packages and then installed all packages. But somehow my system restarted and then while booting it stuck at the point

> checking battery status [OK]

It's there at that status for 5-6 hours. No progress.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is already loading, or is this the BIOS loading? I have this problem too on my old Dell Dimension, but that's BIOS, and has nothing to do with Ubuntu. I have to press F1 to continue. So it may be coincidence.